# Load 1:1 bot as tab in Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

How can I load my 1:1 bot (so; a bot that doesn't work inside a channel) as a tab in Teams? The default manifest options only provide ways to set it as 1:1 (but then each user would have to add the bot  manually) or as channel-bot (but that's more for commands rather then discussions).

So looking for something like this:
http://prntscr.com/nqzh37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bots are supported only as part of conversation. This could be personal or team conversation. Currently, what you are [looking for](https://prnt.sc/nqzh37) is not possible in Microsoft Teams.

You can publish an app to the [Tenant Apps Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/tenant-apps-catalog-teams) from where individual could install it. We are working on feature for Tenant admin to install certain apps for all the users.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info! When can we expect a way to deploy apps to all users?

Comment: any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to 'Add a tab' and choose 'Website' and link to your bot. This *would* require you to run your bot in web chat, but in this way the bot would not be integrated into Teams, wouldn't listen for @mentions (as it wouldn't have been added as an app) yet would be accessible to any user who has access to that Teams channel. (This example links to "mockbot", accessible via the BotFramework-WebChat GitHub [repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)).

Keep in mind, this loads the website hosting the bot. In this example, mockbot utilizes the entire web page. Therefore, we only see the bot. If the bot is embedded with other content on the page, then the other content will be displayed, as well.

**Click the '+' symbol:**

[image]

**Choose 'Website':**

[image]

**Give the bot/app a name and add the link:**

[image]

**Enjoy bot mayhem:**

[image]

Hope of help!

Comment: I appreciate your thinking with me but you have to admit this is not a nice solution and not a possibility for larger organizations ;) It's so weird that (again, see my other points) Microsoft lacks in such easy things as this.. :(